# Trouble sending email via posix script

Tags: linux, script, redhat-enterprise-linux, smtp, posix

I have a smtp server to send emails through Red Hat 7.2
If I type the commands on the server the mail is send successfully.
However, I have tried to create a script to send mails automatically but it fails.
My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
echo "HELO server.com";

echo "MAIL FROM: account@server.com";

echo "RCPT TO: rcptoacc@server.com";

echo "DATA";

echo "From: account@server.com";

echo "To: rcptoacc@server.com";

echo "Subject: Test mail";

echo -e "\n";

echo "Ok.";

echo "Bye";

echo -e "\n\n.";

echo "QUIT";

) | /usr/bin/telnet smtp_server 25
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the server do you see any evidence of the connection and/or errors via the server?  It could be all this gets sent too fast and the telnet connection completes before the server finishes sending its banner back.  After all, SMTP is a dialog with the server, not a monologue

Comment: Also, bash is not POSIX, nor is `echo -e` so this isn't a POSIX script

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001357/4687135) for a way to do it in pure bash (definitely not POSIX though)

Comment: Thanks Eric.
The server throws:
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

I put a sleep on each line but the result is the same.
This script works on HP-UX

Comment: Do you have one before the first line as well, and are the sleeps long enough?  That's a fragile way to go, but when I just tried the script as-is against a mail server I have it complained about the client disconnecting after CONNECT, so it never saw the conversation

Comment: With the leading `sleep` and a `sleep` after each line that is part of the conversation it worked for me, though I still think you'd be better off using a tool for talking smtp or doing it the way in the linked answer

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it as the linked answer. By the way, the script worked adding a sleep after the QUIT line: ` echo "QUIT"; sleep 1; ) | /usr/bin/telnet` ` Thanks for the advice. DASM